# I want to pass the content i get in a variable inside a javascript function to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

My form which contains the summernote editor:

```
<form class="form-group" action="upload.php" style="width: 700px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label> Title: </label>
        <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Title"/><br><br>
        <label> Header Image: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
        <label> Body: </label><div id="summernote"></div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getContent()" name="submit"> Submit </button>

    </form>
```

script to get the content of the editor:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#summernote').summernote();

    });
    function getContent(){$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var content = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
        content=document.getElementById('content').value;});
    }
```

Php code to save the content of the summernote:

```
$uname= $_SESSION['id'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$path= "uploads/".$name;
$body= ;
```

I am trying to save the content of the summernote in the variable $body which is in another file called upload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of div use text area .

```
<textarea name="content" id="summernote"></textarea>
```

Form.

```
  <form class="form-group" action="upload.php" style="width: 700px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label> Title: </label>
        <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Title"/><br><br>
        <label> Header Image: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
        <label> Body: </label>

        <!--Instead of div use text area .-->
        <textarea name="content" id="summernote"></textarea>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"> Submit </button>

    </form>
```

Then no need use getContent. only call summernote for editor.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#summernote').summernote();

    });
    </script>
```

in upload.php you can get the content by $_POST['content']

```
<?php
$title=$_POST['title'];
$path= "uploads/".$name;
echo $body=$_POST['content'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a professional when it comes to this but I would add a hidden input to the form and put the content (getContent) in that field.

```
<form class="form-group" id="theForm" action="upload.php" style="width: 700px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label> Title: </label>
    <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Title"/><br><br>
    <label> Header Image: </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
    <label> Body: </label><div id="summernote"></div>
<input id="content-catcher" type="hidden" name="contentOfEditor" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getContent()" name="submit"> Submit </button>

</form>
```

Script:

```
function getContent(){$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var content = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
    content=document.getElementById('content').value;});
    $('#content-catcher').val(content);
    $('#theForm').submit();
}
```

PHP:

$body= $_POST['contentOfEditor'];